# mysql_insert_id() on galera mysql cluster

Tags: mysql, galera

I have percona mysql galera cluster. It inherited a MyISAM database.
In order for the galera to work it had to alter to innodb. Replication is working so far so good. However I have a php application which calls for mysql_isert_id() after every insert.

In a few words :
1. A big table with many inserts flying in.
2. On every insert (in the old MyISAM db) they lock the table, do the insert query, call mysql_insert_id(), and after that unlock table.

for the replication (innodb), lock table doesn't count anymore. My question is how, can we be sure about the id that mysql_insert_id() returns when there are hundreds of ofther inserts comming in a matter of seconds?

last_insert_id() and mysql_insert_id() return the same value, but as far as I understand  (last_insert) reserves ID before the actual insert(?), and mysql_insert_id do the insert and after that calls for an ID ?

I'm lost in the documentation....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "insert_id" is local to the connection.  *No locking is needed to get the value.*  This applies in all flavors of multi-processing, clustering, engines, etc.

Still, you *may* need "transactions" for other purposes.  You have not described the code enough to say whether you need to exactly replace `LOCK TABLES` (etc) with `BEGIN..COMMIT`.  Or whether some variation is needed.

One thing to learn is the following pattern:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;  -- rows you need to look at before changing
do stuff
UPDATE those rows
COMMIT;
```

The "do stuff" could include a `ROLLBACK` and exit from the flow.

`AUTO_INCREMENT`:

The `INSERT` reserves the id *before* the operation.  In some cases, it will reserve an id but then not use it.  Example: `INSERT IGNORE` when it hits a dup key.

Galera (and any other Multi-Master setup) skips ids.  That is, one node will assign ids 1,4,7,10,...; another node: 2,5,8,...; the third: 3,6,9,...  Depending on the flow of `INSERTs`, you may see most of the numbers used, or you may see lots of gaps.  Also you may "see" id=124 "before" id=123 shows up.

More tips on moving to [*Galera*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/galera) and [*InnoDB*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb)

Comment: Beware of Galery cluster's fail-on-commit behavior if there are multiple simultaneous write nodes: a conflict may only be detected at commit time, rather than at the `FOR UPDATE`. This is because the cluster uses optimistic locking between nodes, whereas each node internally uses pessimistic locking.